# Trying to add image URL from storage to firestore in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Im getting a lot of different errors when I try to pick the image from my gallery and it does not show the image I picked when it should. Please let me know where I'm going wrong. Here is my code

```
File? image;

  Future getImage() async {
    var img = await ImagePicker.platform.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      image = img as File;
    });
  }

  InkWell(
    child: CircleAvatar(
      backgroundImage: image != null
          ? FileImage(image!)
          : NetworkImage("null") as ImageProvider,
      radius: 100,
    ),
    onTap: () async {
      getImage();
    },
  ),
```

These are my errors:

```
The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec: Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///null


E/flutter (10373): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'PickedFile' is not a subtype of type 'File' in type cast 
E/flutter (10373): #0 _AssetListDetailsAddState.getImage.<anonymous closure> (package:asset_management/main.dart:156:19) 
E/flutter (10373): #1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1121:30) 
E/flutter (10373): #2      _AssetListDetailsAddState.getImage (package:asset_management/main.dart:155:5) 
E/flutter (10373): <asynchronous suspension> E/flutter (10373):
```

Answer (score 0):

Try fix `getImage()` to this:

```
Future getImage() async {
    PickedFile? img = await ImagePicker.platform.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      image = File(img.path ?? "");
    });
  }
```

Widget InkWell:

```
        InkWell(
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: image != null
                    ? FileImage(image!)
                    : NetworkImage(
                            "https://jes.edu.vn/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/h%C3%ACnh-%E1%BA%A3nh.jpg")
                        as ImageProvider,
                radius: 100,
              ),
              onTap: () async {
                getImage();
              },
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception looks pretty clear:

`Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///null`

This is breaking your code: `NetworkImage("null") as ImageProvider`, you're passing a string "null".

I'd suggest either to use a "Default" image you store locally or you fetch from a link, or to go with:

```
  backgroundImage: image != null ? FileImage(image!) : null,
     radius: 100,
     ),
```